# In a IBM MobileFirst Server 8 farm, one node is unresponsive

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am having below configuration

```
com.ibm.java.jdk.v8_8.0.3000.20160526_1317

com.ibm.websphere.liberty.v85_8.5.17002.20170523_1818

com.ibm.mobilefirst.foundation.server_8.0.0.20170220_1811
```

There are two nodes running in the farm. All the nodes was working fine for two months, but in last week we had some OS level upgrade so we stopped all the nodes and after OS upgrade we restarted both the nodes, and both nodes were working fine.

But after 24 hrs, in the node1 we started getting the error that "No mxbeans found" so after that whenever we are starting both the nodes then in node1 we are getting the error. While in standalone, both the nodes are working fine.

I am getting the below error message in message.log:

```
[11/3/17 11:00:10:299 UTC] 00000336 com.ibm.mfp.admin.services.v2.ApplicationService             E FWLSE3000E: A server error was detected.
com.ibm.worklight.admin.common.util.exceptions.NotFoundException: FWLSE3041E: No MBean found for MobileFirst project 'mfp'. Possibly the MobileFirst runtime web application for MobileFirst project 'mfp' is not running. If it is running, use JConsole to inspect the available MBeans. If it is not running, full error details are available in the log files of the server.
        at com.ibm.mfp.admin.util.RuntimeMBeanRoutingCaller.call(RuntimeMBeanRoutingCaller.java:52)
        at com.ibm.mfp.admin.services.BaseService.getAdditionalRuntimeInfoAsString(BaseService.java:498)
        at com.ibm.mfp.admin.services.BaseService.getAdditionalRuntimeInfo(BaseService.java:626)
        at com.ibm.mfp.admin.services.v2.ApplicationService.getApplication(ApplicationService.java:593)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.InvokeMethodHandler.handleRequest(InvokeMethodHandler.java:63)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandler.handleRequest(AbstractHandler.java:33)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.CreateInvocationParametersHandler.handleRequest(CreateInvocationParametersHandler.java:54)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandler.handleRequest(AbstractHandler.java:34)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleSubResourceMethod(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:183)
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:110)
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleSubResourceLocator(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:230)
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:115)
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleSubResourceLocator(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:230)
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:115)
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleSubResourceLocator(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:230)
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:115)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindRootResourceHandler.handleRequest(FindRootResourceHandler.java:95)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.HeadMethodHandler.handleRequest(HeadMethodHandler.java:53)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.OptionsMethodHandler.handleRequest(OptionsMethodHandler.java:46)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.SearchResultHandler.handleRequest(SearchResultHandler.java:33)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.ResourceInvocation.handleRequest(ResourceInvocation.java:92)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.Requests.handleRequest(Requests.java:76)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.run(AbstractHandlersChain.java:52)
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequestWithoutFaultBarrier(RequestProcessor.java:207)
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequest(RequestProcessor.java:154)
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:133)
        at com.ibm.mfp.admin.services.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:43)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1290)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:778)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:475)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:152)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:94)
        at com.ibm.mfp.admin.services.RestFilter.doFilter(RestFilter.java:61)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
        at com.ibm.worklight.admin.common.filter.HSTSFilter.doFilter(HSTSFilter.java:110)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:1021)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1143)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:82)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:956)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:280)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:967)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.wrapHandlerAndExecute(HttpDispatcherLink.java:359)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.ready(HttpDispatcherLink.java:318)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:471)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:405)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:285)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:256)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:174)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:83)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:504)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:574)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:929)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1018)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1153)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785)
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information than that. What is your topology? How many nodes? When did you start noticing this issue? What changed that triggered this issue?

Comment: @VivinK, we are having server Farm configuration, there are two nodes running. all the nodes was working fine since last 2 month, but in last week we were having some OS level upgrade so we stopped all the nodes and after OS upgrade we restarted both the nodes. and both nodes was working fine. but after 24 hrs.. in the node1 we started getting the error that "No mxbeans found" so afterthat whenever we are starting both the nodes then in node1 we are getting the error.. while standalone both the nodes are working fine.